# how to create a bottom bar without default bar selected?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have tab layout with bottom bar in a UI. I want to select a default tab but not the bottom bar. But in my code they are both selected at the same time. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can do a work around if you like

add a dummy item in you menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/none"
           android:title="" /> //add this dummy item and set this selected when your view is created
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarItemOne"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_recents"
        android:title="Recents" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarItemtwo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:title="Map" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarItemthree"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view"
        android:title="View" />

</menu>
```

Add your menu in activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);            
        mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemSelected(int resId) {
                if (resId == R.id.bottomBarItemOne) {
                    // the user selected item number one
                }else if(resId == R.id.bottomBarItemtwo){

                }
            }
        });
        mBottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
        // lose the current tab on orientation change.
        mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry change it to setDefaultTabPosition(1);